# Line/Row separator/delimiter in exported CSV using Ruby CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fastercsv, data-import

Is it possible to change the default line separator from newline '\n' or '\r\n' to some other character, e.g '|' while importing.

I know this seems foolish. But i have multiple records in csv file with column address and some addresses might contain '\n' in information.

eg 
Corner Case
    `X|X|X|X|123
    New Addr|X|X|X|`

Normal Case
    `X|X|X|X|123|X|X|X|`

Comment: see http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=comments and comment of "Greg Blass"

Comment: What code are you using to write the CSV out? This should be handled by the built-in CSV library using quotes, like `"123\n..."` where that is as valid a CSV you're going to get. FasterCSV is also deprecated in favour of the Ruby 1.9 built-in CSV library written by the same author.

Comment: i already have exported file. I need to import it correctly.  @tadman i am not sure what is used for CSV out, but i can change it for now

Comment: I'd go with nothing more than `require "csv"` and use that. FasterCSV has bugs that will never get fixed since it's been retired. If you have defects in your CSV, you may need to fix those by hand or find a program that can somehow repair it unless you can patch it yourself with another script.

Comment: i can't correct csv as it comes from some other source. Automating such a defect correction for 7+Gb file will consume a large time. I think i will need to put a hack around when i parse all csv's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the default separators.

```
require 'csv'
CSV.read(csv_file, row_sep: ?|)
```

But that won't help you because regardless of the separators, the CSV library does not allow `\r` or `\n` in unquoted fields.

There's always the poor man's parser:

```
File.read(file).split(row_sep).map { |row| row.split(col_sep) }
```